# How do I run only specific tests in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I think there's a way to run only tests with a given label. Anybody know?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You can tag examples with `:focus` hash attribute. For example,

```ruby
# spec/foo_spec.rb
RSpec.describe Foo do
  it 'is never executed' do
    raise "never reached"
  end

  it 'runs this spec', focus: true do
    expect(1).to eq(1)
  end
end
```

```sh
rspec --tag focus spec/foo_spec.rb
```

More info on [GitHub](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/commit/aa6f7e8744abb4bdc2060fb32a58bd2aeea04e14). (anyone with a better link, please advise)

*(update)*

RSpec is now [superbly documented on relishapp.com](http://relishapp.com/rspec). See the [--tag option](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/tag-option) section for details.

As of v2.6 this kind of tag can be expressed even more simply by including the configuration option `treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values`, which allows you to do:

`describe "Awesome feature", :awesome do`

where `:awesome` is treated as if it were `:awesome => true`.

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23877132/17410) for how to configure RSpec to automatically run 'focused' tests. This works especially well with [Guard](http://guardgem.org/).

Comment: So you don't have to go searching, the direct link to zetetic's suggestion is here (for Rspec 2.12) https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-12/docs/command-line/tag-option

Comment: We added a spec to our suite to ensure code never gets merged with focus: true still in source control.  https://gist.github.com/jwg2s/7361603

Comment: @jwg2s I use a git hook to block commits with `:focus`, which also prevents undesirables like 'binding.pry`, `console.log`, etc. from creeping in to the codebase.

Comment: Are you involved with rspec's documentation efforts?

Comment: @Otheus no, I'm just a fan :) I really like what they did on Relish, but SO just launched its own documentation feature, so we may see some competition.

Comment: Maybe you can point me in the way of documentation that actually describes usage and actual behavior of the `rspec` program :) Because the Relish doc does not.

Answer (score 130):

You can run all tests that contain a specific string with [--example (or -e) option](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/example-option):

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb -e "User is admin"
```

I use that one the most.

Answer (score 109):

Make sure RSpec is configured in your `spec_helper.rb` to pay attention to `focus`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run focus: true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
end
```

Then in your specs, add `focus: true` as an argument:

```
it 'can do so and so', focus: true do
  # This is the only test that will run
end
```

You can also focus tests by changing `it` to `fit` (or exclude tests with `xit`), like so:

```
fit 'can do so and so' do
  # This is the only test that will run
end
```

Comment: In rspec 3.5, it is `config.filter_run_when_matching` and it could work just by adding `:focus` to the example

Comment: If 'focus: true' is accidentally committed your CI will be passing despite not running most of the tests.

Answer (score 70):

alternatively you can pass the line number: `rspec spec/my_spec.rb:75` - the line number can point to a single spec or a context/describe block (running all specs in that block)

Answer (score 59):

You can also string multiple line numbers together with colon :

```
$ rspec ./spec/models/company_spec.rb:81:82:83:103
```

Output:

```
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/models/company_spec.rb"=>[81, 82, 83, 103]}}
```

Comment: This is so gold! ‍♂️

Answer (score 32):

As of RSpec 2.4 (I guess) you can prepend an `f` or `x` to `it`, `specify`, `describe` and `context`:

```
fit 'run only this example' do ... end
xit 'do not run this example' do ... end
```

http://rdoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/ExampleGroup#fit-class_method
http://rdoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/ExampleGroup#xit-class_method

Be sure to have `config.filter_run focus: true` and `config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true` in your `spec_helper.rb`.

Answer (score 10):

In newer versions of RSpec, it's even easier to configure support `fit`:

```
# spec_helper.rb

# PREFERRED
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.filter_run_when_matching :focus
end

# DEPRECATED
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.filter_run focus: true
  c.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
end
```

See:

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/filtering/filter-run-when-matching

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/configuration/run-all-when-everything-filtered

Answer (score 5):

Also you can run specs which have `focus: true` by default

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.filter_run focus: true
  c.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
end
```

Then simply run

```
$ rspec
```

and only focused test will be run

then when you remove `focus: true` all tests well be run again

More information: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/filtering/inclusion-filters

Comment: Is `spec/spec_helper.rb` always included ? Or only if no options are given? Why do test modules have `require 'spec_helber'`, and doesn't having the above code eliminate the possibility of running a single test by specifying the file? I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: `spec_helper.rb` is always included if you have `--require spec_helper` in `.rspec` in the project root.

Answer (score 3):

You can run as `rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb -e "SomeContext won't run this"`.

Comment: This is my favorite approach, tbh.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run by any metadata using `filter_run_including` and `filter_run_excluding`. It allows more flexibility

For example below line will allow running only Rails system tests

```rb
config.filter_run_including type: :system
```

And this line will allow running everything except Rails system tests

```rb
config.filter_run_excluding type: :system
```