# How to run a specific tests of a file using RSpec?

Tags: rspec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run only specific tests in Rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069677/how-do-i-run-only-specific-tests-in-rspec)

I am using RSpec 1.3.2, i tried the options -e, -t, --tag and none works fine. The -l option works but is not specific.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not specific"?

Comment: Well when I specify -l 63, it also includes the line no. 630.