# Running rspec tests for specific contexts

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I have an rspec test defined like below. I know that I can run `rspec -e "guessing"` to run the full block of tests, but I want to run only specific contexts at a time. This way I can code the "correctly" tests first, and then later the "incorrectly" portion. Is there a command line way run the specified tests without naming them individually?

```
describe 'guessing' do
  context 'correctly' do
    it 'changes correct guess list' do

    end
    it 'returns true' do

    end
  end
  context 'incorrectly' do
    it 'changes wrong guess list' do

    end
    it 'returns true' do

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can reference each line number. `$ rspec file:3` runs the `'changes correct guess list'` example.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116668/rspec-how-to-run-a-single-test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run only specific tests in Rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069677/how-do-i-run-only-specific-tests-in-rspec)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-e` to match any part of the description, so `rspec -e incorrectly` will run those two tests. (I don't know of a way to only match "correctly", as it's also a substring of "incorrectly".)

You can also use [a line number reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116744/476979) to match a `context` block: `rspec your_spec.rb:2` (given the above content exactly, with `context 'correctly' do` on line 2) will run that set of specs.

Comment: Assuming it is part of a larger string, to match "correctly" without matching "incorrectly", just add a preceding space: " correctly".